# Validation pattern of javascript

Tags: regex, validation

my validation is only input 0-9 and x,X

do not input 'space' or 'negative' numbers.

what type of pattern use??

/[^\dxX]/gi it not work on -1 , -2 ,etc

Comment: Your question contradicts itself.  You first say `do not input 'space' or 'negative' numbers`.  Then you say `it not work on -1, -2, etc`.  Please consider adding clarification and example input values and output expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex you use a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^` which will NOT match a digit `\d`, `x` or `X`.

You could move the `^` to the beginning of the regex where its meaning changes to assert position at the begin of the line.
After that you can use a character class which will match a digit or x and use `$` to assert the end of the line.

Use the `i` case insensitive flag to match `K` or `k`.

[`^[\dx]$`](https://regex101.com/r/ekjjAB/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "0",
  "1",
  "9",
  "x",
  "X",
  "10",
  "99",
  "a",
  "A",
  "-1",
  "-10"
];
let pattern = /^[\dx]$/i;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```